# Xsl view, web relative link?

Tags: xslt-list-view-web-part

I have a custom list definition that defines some view. These views are linked to a custom xsl file because of some formatting rules (red row when field X equals Y).

In this xsl, I'd like to add a link to a custom page with the ID of the item. The result should be : `weburl/pages/mypage.aspx?id=123`.

I have by now something like this, at the very end of my xsl file :

```
  <td>
    <a href="../Pages/mypage.aspx?MyID={@ID}">
      Show
    </a>
  </td>
```

This is working from my site home page (which is /pages/home.aspx), but this won't work from the list itself because of the relative url.

1. is the xsl approach the correct way to defines such link ?
2. if yes, is there any token or similar way to create SPWeb relative url ?

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're including correctly *main.xsl* in your template, use **$ServerRelativeUrl** global parameter.

Example:

```
<td>
  <a href="{$ServerRelativeUrl}/Pages/mypage.aspx?MyID={@ID}">
    Show
  </a>
</td>
```

MSDN reference for XSLT global parameters available here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff806158.aspx

All these global parameters are defined in the *main.xsl* file:

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\XSL\main.xsl

Comment: That works like a charm. I definitively have to dive this part of SharePoint. Thanks a lot.